# R: How to split a specific column based on symbol?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to do POS Tag in  my text mining process.

This is my POS Tag result format.

```
  Word & POS Tag
1 cmp/NN conditioner/NN
2 contains/VBZ the/DT grinding/VBG
3 diamond/NN
```

But It's mixed with POS Tags.
I prefer to get the format like this:

```
  Word                     POS Tag
1 cmp conditioner          NN-NN
2 contains the grinding    VBZ-DT-VBG
3 diamond                  NN
```

Have anyway to spilit words and POS Tags in R??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the parts before and after the / separately with the empty string.  No packages are used.

```
cbind(gsub("/\\w+", "", L), gsub(" ", "-", gsub("\\w+/", "", L)))
```

giving:

```
     [,1]                    [,2]        
[1,] "cmp conditioner"       "NN-NN"     
[2,] "contains the grinding" "VBZ-DT-VBG"
[3,] "diamond"               "NN"
```

**Note:** Input in reproducible form assumed to be:

```
L <- c("cmp/NN conditioner/NN", "contains/VBZ the/DT grinding/VBG", "diamond/NN")
```

Comment: Thanks. This code is very clear and efficient for me.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to extract the substring after reading the dataset with `readLines`

```
v1 <- sapply(str_extract_all(lines[-1], "\\w+(?=[/])"), paste, collapse=" ")
v2 <- sapply(str_extract_all(lines[-1], "(?<=[/])\\w+"), paste, collapse="-")
nm1 <- trimws(scan(text=lines[1], what = "", sep="&", quiet =TRUE))
d1 <- setNames(data.frame(v1, v2, stringsAsFactors= FALSE), nm1)
d1
#                   Word    POS Tag
#1       cmp conditioner      NN-NN
#2 contains the grinding VBZ-DT-VBG
#3               diamond         NN
```

NOTE: `tidyverse` packages are used which are compact and easy

---

Or another option is `strsplit`

```
 do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(lines[-1], "[/ ]"), function(x) {
      x1 <- x[-1]; c(paste(x1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], collapse=" "), 
      paste(x1[c(FALSE, TRUE)], collapse="-"))}))
 #       [,1]                    [,2]        
 #[1,] "cmp conditioner"       "NN-NN"     
 #[2,] "contains the grinding" "VBZ-DT-VBG"
 #[3,] "diamond"               "NN"
```

NOTE: Absolutely No packages used - 100% confirmation

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("file.txt")
```